# How to link to a Relationship Matrix

Tags: enterprise-architect

I just try to set up my documentation in Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect.
I have an overview diagram which links to other diagrams.
A certain Relationship Matrix is important for my documentation, so I would like to link to it, but since it is not a diagram, but a view on the model, I just wonder if it is possible to link somehow to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, just found the answer through another question:

If you create a Hyperlink in EA, you can change the type to link to a Matrix...